# Is there a way to use telnet within an ssh connection in Robot Framework?

Tags: python, testing, ssh, telnet, robotframework

There is a node where I ssh into and start a script remotely by Robot Framework (SSHLibrary.Start Command or Execute Command). This remote script starts a telnet connection to another node which is hidden from outside. This telnet call seems to be a blocking event to Robot. I use RIDE for test execution and it simply stops working. I can send stop signals inefficiently. Is it possible to spawn telnet within ssh?

Answer (score 3):

*Everything* is possible.

Let's describe your scenario as: Robot Framework runs on machine A. The test connects A to machine B via ssh and B to machine C via telnet.

From your question **is not clear at which step the test gets stuck**. Does the test actually establish the telnet connection ? Does the telnet process actually start on B ?

Here you should consider two related issues.

The first is that Robot Framework executes the test in a single thread. This means that the test does *not* progress until a keyword returns. If you want the telnet session to be open while the test continues, you must use **SSHLibrary.start command** and not *execute command*.

The second point is controlling programmatic-ally the telnet session. The telnet client must support some kind of batch execution (e.g. not asking the password or flushing the input).  Make sure you are able to issue commands on C from the test. You should be able to redirect commands for C using **write** keywords. You can check telnet client to work by cat-ting a file of commands from its standard input. Something like

```
cat commands_for_c.txt | telnet ...to..c...
```

Comment: Your description about my scenario is correct. Earlier I tried to start telnet with Start Command and Execute Command, too. Then it looked as if the connection was not established. Now I use simply Write and I get back the prompt from telnet, but Robot seems to forget my prompt preset or something. See my other comment to sdmythos_gr's answer.

Comment: the cat with the pipeline might be a nice way to go about this... The set prompt functionality, if I am not mistaken has changed in the latest sshlibrary and there might be a case that it is set only once per connection. In out test we use one of the previous versions of the ssh library (I think 0.9) so before any write command we set the expected prompt. i.e. Set prompt Password: and then write password. Then set prompt > and then write commands...

Comment: I took a look at the changelog of SSH Library. In my understanding it says that the prompt used to be set globally (and you can change it as many times as you want) and all connections used that, but now every single connection can have its own prompt.

Comment: Pipelineing in the test or manually ? Try to manually login in B and run telnet with the pipeline. If it does not work, neither can the test! Your telnet client must be able to work in pipeline .

Comment: I tried it manually and it caused immediate closure of the telnet connection. I read in other threads that netcat would be an alternative, but I could not figure out how to use that - it was unable to resolve C's address.

Comment: The important thing is if the telnet client executed or not the commands from the file. After sending the file through the pipe it is normal that the connection get closed, as the input terminates.

If it does, then it works. In the test you will keep the connection open, writing the commands.

Comment: Let's assume I have a command.txt which contains only one word: help. The 'help' is the most basic command which lists the available commands within the telnet connection. If I simply execute this: 'telnet myhost myport', I can see telnet's login information and greetings message and I can type 'help' by myself and I get the list. If I do this: 'cat command.txt | telnet myhost myport', I can see the login info and greetings and 'Connection closed by foreign host.' message and telnet session is closed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Some clients flush the input before or after reading the password. Try to use a command line option to specify the password. Also try to execute _ls_ which works only if the client is really connected.

Answer (score 2):

We haven't exactly used the method with telnet but with another ssh session or other shells that we cannot access otherwise...

Open an ssh connection to the first machine. 
On this connection, use SSHLibrary keywords like Set Prompt, Write and Read or Read Until Prompt to manually open a telnet connection to the next machine.
Write and Read Keywords can be used a bit like the expect and spawn...

Comment: Write and Read Until Prompt combination seems to work. Formerly I tried to start telnet with Start Command and Execute Command without success. Now I get the prompt from telnet, but I cannot send any more command. However, I set the prompt properly, the test fails with "No match found for '/there is a linebreak here/' in 3 seconds". I am clueless.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I use ssh connection to send telnet command in Robot Framework like that:

```
SSHLibrary.Open Connection    host=***    port=22    timeout=60    alias=ssh    prompt=:~ >
SSHLibrary.Login    username=***    password=***    delay=1s
SSHLibrary.Switch Connection    index_or_alias=ssh
SSHLibrary.Write    lxc-attach -n 0x1018
SSHLibrary.Read Until Prompt
SSHLibrary.Write    telnet 1.2.3.4 2323
SSHLibrary.Read Until    $
SSHLibrary.Write    sendX 1115 1 0 0 0 0
SYSTEM Close SSH Connection
```